# Javascript/Jquery - too much recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a script that scrolls table data in a continuous loop.
The issue I have is, I keep getting the following error:

> "too much recursion".

Does anyone know how I can use the script without this error happening?

```
$.fn.confScrollUp=function(){

var self=this,conf=self.children()
setInterval(function(){
    conf.slice(30).hide()
    conf.filter(':hidden').eq(0).slideDown()
    conf.eq(0).slideUp(4000, "linear",function(){
        $(this).appendTo(self)
        conf=self.children()
    })
},1)
return this;
}


$(function(){
    $('section').confScrollUp()
})
```

There is not user interaction, its just for displaying data.

Comment: Are you sure you want that `setInterval` firing once every millisecond?

Comment: @Andy Hi to be honest, no.I just need the scroll to work but I am not sure what to change.

Comment: Can you add it to a jsfiddle or something so we can see it not working?

Comment: @Andy Hi, https://jsfiddle.net/Blackbox/dsm3dg55/10/ I have changed the code to scroll faster but its too fast.

Comment: That isn't producing any errors :)

Comment: @Andy I know, it works when this line conf.eq(0).slideUp(4000, "linear",function() is set to 800 but when set to 4000, which slow's the scroll it errors.

Comment: [This seems to work ok.](https://jsfiddle.net/ndgte9yq/3/). I kept in the interval but increased it to 100 ms.

Comment: @Andy Great, that works. Many thanks for your time. Make it an answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work error-free if you increase the `setInterval` interval. Here I've chosen `100` to go along with the increase in the slider value to `4000`.

```
$.fn.infiniteScrollUp=function(){
    var self=this,conf=self.children()
    setInterval(function(){
        conf.slice(10).hide();
      conf.filter(':hidden').eq(0).slideDown()
      conf.eq(0).slideUp(4000, "linear",function(){
        $(this).appendTo(self);
        conf=self.children();
      });
    },100)
    return this;
}
```